# How to achieve this card UI image flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How do I place the image in this way in a card

[image]

Comment: Using **Stack** Widget you may achieve this overlap of image over the container.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Stack widget. You can determine the position of the image with Positioned Widget.
For Example :

```
 Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Card()
    Positioned(
    top: 0,
    bottom 10, 
    // vs...
    child :Image(),
    )
  ],
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way:

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
   // insert all decorations here (color, shape)...
  ),
  child: Row(
    children: [
      Container(
        child: Image()
        transform: Matrix4.translationValues(0.0, -50.0, 0.0),
      ),
      Container (
       // insert here the other things that are in that card
      ),
    ]
  ),
);
```